# Setting a value to NULL in ‘BEFORE UPDATE’ mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.type != OLD.type or NEW.agency_name != OLD.agency_name) and NEW.type = 'INDEPENDENT' THEN
        SET NEW.agency_name = NULL;
    END IF;
END; 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It should keep `NULL` value in `agency_name` field whenever the `type` is `INDEPENDENT`. And it works as expected only if I set `agency_name` to anything else but `NULL`, e.g.g `SET NEW.agency_name = 'some value’`.

How can I fix this?

**Update 22/02/2016:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('INDEPENDENT','AGENCY') NOT NULL,
  `agency_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `created`, `modified`, `username`, `password`, `type`, `agency_name`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(), '1234567', '1234567', 'INDEPENDENT', NULL, '')
```

Now if you update the `agency_name` field, it gets updated.

```
UPDATE users SET agency_name = '12312’;
```

But if you set `NEW.agency_name = 'some'` in the trigger the value updates to 'some'.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86462e/1).

Comment: @OP: post some existing records along with your post update results.

Comment: @RavinderReddy, I updated the post.

Comment: @wchiquito, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07178/2/0

Comment: Remember: `You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.`. See [3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: This can be useful: [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df6c/1). Adjust according to your business rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @wchiquito, [3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) was really helpful, and `!(firstValue <=> secondValue)` did the trick.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_update_trigger;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.type != OLD.type or !(NEW.agency_name <=> OLD.agency_name)) and NEW.type = 'INDEPENDENT' THEN
        SET NEW.agency_name := NULL;
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```